# How I can force Vue Router to reload my page when I'm trying to navigate in the current location?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

Actually I have my project like this.

- Views

  - Home.vue
  - Classroom.vue
- App.vue

In the `Home.vue` I have my the content and the login form. Basically, if you are not connected yet you have the submit the login (if the login is correct then `isAuth = true`) and the form hide and you can now see the content (list of classrooms)

```
<div v-if="isAuth" @click="goToClassroomView"> List of classrooms </div>
<div v-if="!isAuth"> Here is the login form... </div>
```

In my App.vue, I have an app-bar and main with a router-view with my logout function.

```
<v-app-bar app color="#2196f3">
    <v-btn @click="logout()">logout</logout>
</v-app-bar>

<v-main class="white">
      <router-view></router-view> //Either Home.vue or Classroom.vue
</v-main>
```

Here is my logout function inside the App.vue :

```
 logout() {
        this.$store.dispatch('LOGOUT')
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push('/') //go to home.vue
        })
      }
```

So here comes my problem. When I click on the logout button when i'm in the home.app, the user logout correctly but my page is now a empty list of classrooms (because there's no user and `isAuth` is a variable inside the `Home.vue` so I can't affect it from the `App.vue`).

So is it possible to reload the page when I'm in the Home page or access to `isAuth` from the `App.vue`, so when an user logout in the home page, the list of classroom disappear and it shows the form ?

Comment: I suggest you to create a **login.vue**. Or in your `logout` `then` isAuth.value = false

Comment: But isAuth is inside the Home component

Comment: **session.storage** if you don't want to use **vuex**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `isAuth` variable to vuex store state.
Then in `LOGOUT` action you change `isAuth` state to `false`.